# Write to join table getting params from nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm at my very first app in Rails 5 (Ruby 2.4.0) and I have several issues; the biggest ones (at the moment) is retrieving parameters from a nested form.

My questions and, below, my files:

1)  First of all, is this the correct way to create a model’s nested form and write in a join table?

2)  How can I get the params from the select in the nested form: I am not able to retrieve the city_id (from within app/models/link_patient_address_city.rb)  and store it in link_patient_address_cities table.

3)  How can I get the just created patient id in order to write it in link_patient_address_cities table?

Thanks.

I have 3 tables:

1. patients (:id, :name)
2. a JOIN table link_patient_address_cities (:id, :patient_id,
   :city_id)
3. cities (:id, :name)

When I create a new patient I want to store the city_id and the newly created patient_id in the link_patient_address_cities table.

These are my model, controller and form files:

**app/models/patient.rb**

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
has_many :link_patient_address_cities
has_many :cities, :through => :link_patient_address_cities
has_many :phone_contacts
has_many :patient_emails
def
link_patient_address_cities_attributes=(attributes)
    # Process the attributes hash
  end
end
```

**app/models/ link_patient_address_city.rb**

```
class LinkPatientAddressCity < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :patient #, index: true
belongs_to :city #, index: true

    def self.insert_recapito(p)
    l=LinkPatientAddressCity.new
    l.city_id=p[:link_patient_address_cities_attributes[:city_id]]
    l.patient_id=2
    l.save
    end
end
```

**app/controllers/ link_patient_address_cities_controller.rb**

```
class LinkPatientAddressCitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link_patient_address_city, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /link_patient_address_cities
  # GET /link_patient_address_cities.json
  def index
    @link_patient_address_cities = LinkPatientAddressCity.all
  end

  # GET /link_patient_address_cities/1
  # GET /link_patient_address_cities/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /link_patient_address_cities/new
  def new
    @link_patient_address_city = LinkPatientAddressCity.new
  end

  # GET /link_patient_address_cities/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /link_patient_address_cities
  # POST /link_patient_address_cities.json
  def create
    @link_patient_address_city = LinkPatientAddressCity.new(link_patient_address_city_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link_patient_address_city.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link_patient_address_city, notice: 'Link patient address city was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link_patient_address_city }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link_patient_address_city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /link_patient_address_cities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /link_patient_address_cities/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link_patient_address_city.update(link_patient_address_city_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link_patient_address_city, notice: 'Link patient address city was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link_patient_address_city }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link_patient_address_city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /link_patient_address_cities/1
  # DELETE /link_patient_address_cities/1.json
  def destroy
    @link_patient_address_city.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to link_patient_address_cities_url, notice: 'Link patient address city was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link_patient_address_city
      @link_patient_address_city = LinkPatientAddressCity.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def link_patient_address_city_params
      params.require(:link_patient_address_city).permit(:last_address)
    end
end
```

**app/models/city.rb**

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :province #, index: true
    has_many :link_patient_address_cities
    has_many :patients, :through => :link_patient_address_cities
end
```

**/app/views/patients/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(patient) do |f| %>
<%= f.label : name %>
<%= f.text_field : name %>
<%= f.fields_for :link_patient_address_cities do |lpac_form| %>
<%= lpac_form.collection_select :city_id, City.order(:city_name), :city_code, :city_name, {include_blank:"Select one..."}, {class: "form-control"} %>
<% end %>
<% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**The generated markup of the select is:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="patient[link_patient_address_cities_attributes][0][city_id]" id="patient_link_patient_address_cities_attributes_0_city_id">
```

Comment: Is the join table necessary for what you're doing? Do patients actually need to have more than one city associated with them? Your view as it is now only allows for one city. If you only need one, consider changing it so patient belongs_to city.

Comment: Yes, I need a patient to have more cities. In this way I can have an history of all the addresses he/she has changed during time (in join table there is a "last address" boolean field too).
Furthermore, in db I have a lot of other tables joined togheter in this way; hence, if I understand how to correctly manage this case I shall do the same for the other part of the db.